# Rotating Icons using JavaScript not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="doll.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../project/bootstrap.min.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../project/style.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../project/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
            $(".rotation_90deg").click(function(){
                                                    $(this).toggleClass("down")  ; 
                                        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#"><div class="fa fa-anchor  rotation_90deg"></div></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

associated CSS:

```
   .rotation_90deg{
   -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
   -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
   transition: all 2s linear;
}

.rotation_90deg.down{
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
   transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

I am trying to rotate an icon using this code but  it's not  working, would someone be able to provide a solution or parallel code?

Comment: First: when you're using **jQuery** functions then you must inlcude **jQuery Library** first in your **Dom** and Secondly only after that use those function in `$(document).ready(function(e) { /* write your functions here */ });`

Comment: i don't know who are the down voting jerks without mention   what is the problem with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the code within [document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)  or move the script tag at the end of the HTML to run only after elements are loaded.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rotation_90deg").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("down");
    });
  });
</script>
```

```css
.rotation_90deg {
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
.rotation_90deg.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rotation_90deg").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("down");
    });
  });
</script>
<a href="#">
  <div style="margin-top:200px" class="fa fa-anchor  rotation_90deg">11</div>
</a>
```

```css
.rotation_90deg {
  -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  transition: all 2s linear;
}
.rotation_90deg.down {
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
  <div style="margin-top:200px" class="fa fa-anchor  rotation_90deg">11</div>
</a>
<script>
  $(".rotation_90deg").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("down");
  });
</script>
```

---

In case elements are dynamically added then you should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to listen to the click event of the element.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '".rotation_90deg", unction() {
      $(this).toggleClass("down");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: sorry ,i don't think this is a correct solution.you can check the link given below http://jsfiddle.net/zakirshakir/3v2egwfs/790/

Comment: but it does not work when i copy it to my pad,that is the real problem

Comment: yeah i know,but it's not working when i copy that code in to my note pad,that is the problem

Comment: @dreamhunter : any console error ? is the elements are dynamically added?